# How to get a string from an array of strings so that it can be used with SetText? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

I am doing a quiz app, with a lot of questions in different chapters. Every chapter of course is an array.

But now, I have come to the point where I need for one specific chapter to pull ALL the questions and answers from ALL the chapters. So basically its an array within another array/s.

```
 public void shuffleChapterRandomTest() {
    shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest = new String[chapterRandomTestQuestions.length];
    for (int k = 0; k < shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest.length; k++) {
        shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[k] = String.valueOf(k);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest));
    Log.i("TAG", "shuffle: " + shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[0] + " " + shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[1]);
}


public static String shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[];


private String chapterRandomTestQuestions[][] = {

 //This are all the chapters being called

        Questions,
        chapterTwoQuestions,
        chapterThreeQuestions,
        chapterFourQuestions,
        chapterFiveQuestions,
        chapterSixQuestions,
        chapterSevenQuestions,
        chapterEightQuestions,
        chapterNineQuestions,
        chapterTenQuestions,
        chapterElevenQuestions,
        chapterTwelveQuestions,
        chapter13Questions,
        chapter14Questions


};

//This is my get method

public String[] getChapterRandomTestQuestion(String a) {



    return chapterRandomTestQuestions[Integer.parseInt(a)];


}
```

When I try to pull the string from "questions" as setText for the TextView.

```
 private void updateQuestion() {

    if (questionnumber < questionBank.getChapterRandomTestLength()) {

        storeUserData.setInt(Constants.TOTAL_QUESTION,questionBank.getChapterRandomTestLength());
        binding.tvCountQuestion.setText(questionnumber+1+"/"+questionBank.getChapterRandomTestLength());


        binding.tvQuestion.setText(questionBank.getChapterRandomTestQuestion(shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[questionnumber]));
        binding.tvAnsOne.setText(questionBank.getChapterRandomTestChoice(shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[questionnumber], 1));
        binding.tvAnsTwo.setText(questionBank.getChapterRandomTestChoice(shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[questionnumber], 2));
        binding.tvAnsTnree.setText(questionBank.getChapterRandomTestChoice(shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[questionnumber], 3));
        answer = questionBank.getChapterRandomTestCorrectAnswer(shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[questionnumber]);
        questionnumber++;
```

It shows an error:

> Required: Java.lang.String 
>   Found: Java.lang.String[]

How can I pull the questions and answers as Strings and not as arrays. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
questionBank.getChapterRandomTestQuestion(shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[questionnumber])
```

You're retrieving a `String[]`, representing one of the entries in `chapterRandomTestQuestions`. You need to use

```
questionBank.getChapterRandomTestQuestion(shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[questionnumber])[someNumber]
```

Also, I notice you're filling `shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest` with String representations of Integers. Why not make that an `int[]` instead, and avoid having to cast to String and then back to int?

And another note/question: I think you may have written the wrong thing for your arrays. The syntax is

```
SomeObject[] variable
```

not

```
SomeObject variable[]
```